# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<) System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, xss

I'm using WEB API 2. Whenever somebody tries to insert the script into my API, I want to throw 404 or 400 error with a custom message, and not 500 error.

This is different from SO question - [Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client) because I don't want to allow, but throw custom errors.

Basically, I want to just return if the script is detected, without executing any controllers, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide some clarity on why you want to do this?

I would recommend that you look at the global.asax event Application_BeginRequest() and check the unvalidated properties in a custom method here.  That will ensure you dont need to completely disable the validation and leave yourself vulnerable?

Comment: But as mentioned in this answer, I won't be able to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/15578829/2390553

Comment: I want to do it this way, bcoz that's how its written in the user story. I tried to talk with my senior, but he is adamant on doing it this way only

Comment: Yes but by hooking into this on the global.asax you would still be protected by the default behaviour (500) if your method doesn't throw a custom exception.  I'm not advocating that you disable it, but rather adding your own method before the 500 is thrown by the application?  This is the closest I can suggest to offer you the best of both worlds.